# Open attachment that contains forwarded email (MIME type message/rfc822)

Tags: stock-email-app, attachments

When I forward an email with Mutt from my laptop, Mutt adds the forwarded email as an attachment with MIME type "message/rfc822".

Unfortunately, Android's stock email client "com.android.email" version 8.1.0 displays the received email like this:

[image: Email app screenshot saying "Couldn't download. Touch to retry"]

Two things are wrong with that:

- It doesn't show the forwarded email's content.
- It doesn't show the content of the non-forwarded email, the body of the email I wrote in Mutt.

The email displays properly when using K-9 Mail.

Is there a way to make the email app show the email and its attachment?

---

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy J5 running LineageOS.

Comment: You're right, I had `set mime_forward` because I wanted to [forward attachments per default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535198/include-attachments-per-default-when-forwarding-mail). If I unset `mime_forward`, the forwarded email is just text (not a `message/rfc822`) and the stock email app shows it fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail cannot support this as I understand from [FairEmail](https://email.faircode.eu/) discussion on XDA (outlook mail client has related limitations).

There is a workaround, in case one is willing to have the forwarded email as text and not attachment.

OP had set `mime_forward` because they wanted to [forward attachments per default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535198/296774)
. If this is unset as per [mutt documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#mime-forward) (to `ask-no` or `ask-yes`), the forwarded email is just text (not a `message/rfc822`) and the stock email app shows it fine as [confirmed](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226024/open-attachment-that-contains-forwarded-email-mime-type-message-rfc822/226076#comment294729_226024) by them.

Comment: The FairEmail discussion on XDA sounds interesting. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: You can search for "rfc822", even better would be reach out to developer--he is very prompt and helpful

Comment: It isn't a single instance I was quoting but the general sense of difficulties with various email clients, like [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81512369&postcount=11943). My *guess* is FairEmail will support your need but it's best confirmed by you checking and if not asking developer to consider. I find him unbelievably supportive and tries his best to accommodate. I answered it just so that it may help somebody who comes looking for a solution, though this may not be what you want